# Narrowing generec type in typescript

Tags: typescript

typescript v4.4.4
Why generic type is not narrowed after type guard? How do I fix it?

```js
type Data = A | B | C
type G<T extends Data> = {
  type: 'a' | 'b'
  data: T
}
type A = {
  foo: string
}
type B = {
  bar: string
}
type C = {
  foobar: string
}
const isA = (item: G<Data>): item is G<A> => item.type === 'a'

const throwOnA = (item: G<Data>): G<Exclude<Data, A>> => {
  if (!isA(item)) return item // Item still G<Data> instead of G<B | C>
  throw Error('is A')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because Typescript cannot narrow `G<Data>` down that way. It only knows that `item` is of type `G<Data>` and not of type `G<A>`, but it cannot conclude that the resulting generic type should be `G<B | C>`. My best guess is that it's a limitation in its type resolver.

As a workaround you can create a function for the opposite check:

```
const isNotA = (item: G<Data>): item is G<Exclude<Data, A>> => item.type !== 'a' // or return !isA(item)

const throwOnA = (item: G<Data>): G<Exclude<Data, A>> => {
  if (isNotA(item)) return item // Item is now G<B | C>
  throw Error('is A')
}
```

I know this takes away some of the magic, but it's the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code. The main one is that `G<Data>` is not a union type, so narrowing is not going to work how you want. The other one (which isn't causing this issue, but it's part of the fix) is that your `G` type allows mismatched properties, e.g. `{type: 'a', data: B}`. The solution is to use a discriminated union type.

```
type GUnion =
  | {type: 'a', data: A}
  | {type: 'b', data: B | C} // or make B and C separate

type G<T extends Data> = Extract<GUnion, {data: T}>

const isA = (item: G<Data>): item is G<A> => item.type === 'a';

const throwOnA = (item: G<Data>): G<Exclude<Data, A>> => {
  if(!isA(item)) {
    return item;
  }
  throw Error('is A')
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UCCUA+UBCWoDCAsAFCiTopQDeAZgPb0BcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYBfUuWh5U1AEZwOLdt35Cy4aASp1GUmW069BpYcqgBxAKo8u9HilJR81ESwDkcRwBooAEwRwWaRbex7ZScJN09vFjxsAgEoAHo4qHoOKABbOABrUSg4Hg9CNggwaQQIfSUKIwAeABUoCAAPYAg81lhvAD4qAFEmjjgAY2Aq03NLd2ovRBYagQ7ygct2KC5WDFQACi5m1JZq+EQOgEoWbYhUlbbqtC7kLrPUgDoRFGRUZ0cAbgWl4ChgAAWHHoAHcAPI8dZQLY7PZVA5wY5w3oDAA2AFcPBB4d53Ddbl1qDYVrQNgBCVZoGHnI5HGjE2wcCDAdEcKwPb4kWz+f5A0FQbocYEcDaOVboRxHUgCTlAA)

Note that you can also now write `if(item.type !== 'a')` instead of `if(!isA(item))` to narrow the type, if you think that is clearer.